# overflow: auto in nested flexboxes

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm currently experimenting with flexbox layouts and have a problem, that `overflow` wont get applied, when I nest multiple flexboxes.

As long as I just use one level of flex boxes (see example 1), everything works fine: As soon as its content exceed the given space, scrollbars are applied to the red box (`#top`).

If I, however, introduce another layer of flexboxes (see example two), there is no scrollbar on the blue box (`#right`). Instead the scrollbars appear on the body element completely ignoring the `overflow: auto` setting on the blue box.

So my question is: **How can I get `overflow` to work when using nested flexboxes?**

Remark: I tested this with Chrome45, Firefox 40 and IE11. The behavior is consistent across all.

Below is the code as well as a fiddle link for both cases.

---

**(1) Just one flexbox, no nesting**

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sirko/yLp2zhv5/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
      ...
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        blub
    </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#container{
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#top {
    background-color: red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
        overflow: auto;
    white-space:pre;
}


#bottom {
    background-color: green;
    height: 4em;
}
```

---

**(2) nested flexboxes**

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sirko/01je0ace/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="left">
        </div>
        <div id="right">
          ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        blub
    </div>
</div>
```

```
html, body { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#container{
    background-color: yellow;
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

#top {
    background-color: red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#right {
    white-space: pre;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 5em;
}

#left {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: orange;
}

#bottom {
    background-color: green;
    height: 4em;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latest browsers implement the new `auto` as the initial value of `min-height`.

That forces `#top` to be at least as tall as its content.

So you need to undo that:

```css
#top {
  min-height: 0;
}
```

Then `#top` can be shorter than its content. `#right` will be stretched to be as tall as `#top`, and the content of `#top` might overflow.

```css
html, body { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
#container{
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
#top {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 0;
}
#right {
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5em;
}
#left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: orange;
}
#bottom {
  background-color: green;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      11
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
      1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    blub
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! IE still seems to fail, but at least it is working somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative answer: just specify `flex:1` rather than `flex-grow:0` on #top.**  Or specify `flex-basis:0`.  `flex:1` implicitly sets `flex: 1 1 0`, i.e. the third 0 means `flex-basis:0`.

This matters because the default initial value of `flex-basis` is *not* 0 but `auto`, which in turn effectively means `content`-sized and thus you need to resort to `min-height`.  Like the OP, I found `min-height` somewhat out-of-nowhere and a bit bewildering, and the `flex` notation less so.

Updated snippet:

http://codepen.io/yaaang/pen/gayqPE

[From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#valdef-flex-flex-basis):

> [The third component in `flex`] sets the flex-basis longhand and specifies the flex
>   basis: the initial main size of the flex item, before free space is
>   distributed according to the flex factors. It takes the same values as
>   the width property (except auto is treated differently) and an
>   additional content keyword. When omitted from the flex shorthand, its
>   specified value is 0%.
>
> If the specified flex-basis is auto, the used
>   flex basis is the computed value of the flex item’s main size
>   property. If that value is itself auto, then the used flex basis is
>   automatically-determined based on its content (i.e. sized as for
>   content).